# oracle query to find matches in two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

two tables in database, similar structure below.

-I need the list of elements from TABLE1 where P1 matches S3 and at the same time P2 matches S2.

```
+            TABLE1           +        +           TABLE2            +
+---------+---------+---------+        +---------+---------+---------+
| P1      | P2      | P3      |        + S1      | S2      | S3      |
+---------+---------+---------+        +---------+---------+---------+
| A       | B       | C       |        | P       | B       | A       |
| B       | B       | C       |        | A       | G       | T       |
| Z       | K       | R       |        | T       | M       | T       |
| T       | S       | L       |        | M       | K       | Z       |
| W       | W       | W       |        | W       | W       | W       |
+---------+---------+---------+        +---------+---------+---------+
```

so, as a result I shall get:

```
+            RESULT           +
+---------+---------+---------+
| P1      | P2      | P3      |
+---------+---------+---------+
| A       | B       | C       |
| Z       | K       | R       |
| W       | W       | W       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

the question : what is the oracle query that does this join, compare and match operations.
Note: using a loop is discouraged.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not against any rule here on SO to post homework, but if it is, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to combine both tables.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.P1 = b.S3 AND
               a.P2 = b.S2
```

**[CLICK here for more type of Joins (Oracle Docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm)**

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b
WHERE a.P1 = b.S3 AND a.P2 = b.S2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`INNER JOIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm):

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
     ON (table1.P1 = table2.S3 AND table1.P2 = table2.S2);
```

Comment: I might do something wrong but, it gives some rows multiple times.

Comment: @bluebrain it returns some rows multiple because it matches on the second table multiple times.

Comment: all 3 answers are working like a charm, which one should I accept?